# CSS3 Modal Background Not Transparent

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I am creating a Pure CSS3 Modal.

Along the way I got two issues.

1. The Background is not changing to transparent black color when the modal was click. 
   (if you've seen modal before you know what I mean cause basically it will force the background to be transparent type color.) See Screenshots:

![The original background color is #fff or white
Look at the background its color grayish tranparent color when the the modal was active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrwRB.jpg)

2. I've been thinking how can I make this 3D Flip Horizontal Animate or create a nice and smooth rotation when coming instead of just plain moving from top to bottom.

Here's my HTML:

```
<p><a href="#modal" class="btn go">Display Modal</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
                <h1>What is a modal?</h1>
            <div class="copy">
                <p>A modal window is any type of window that is a child (secondary window) to a parent window and usurps the parent's control. It is commonly associated with an Internet Web site pop-up window that stays in front of the original window.  A user may not press any controls or enter any information on the parent window (the original window which opened the modal) until the modal has been closed.</p>
            </div>

                <a href="#" class="btn">Close Modal</a>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my stylesheet codes:

```
    .container {
    width:50%;
    margin:90px auto
}


#modal {
    background:#97d2f1;
    left:50%;
    top:-50%;
    width:80%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin:-250px 0 0 -40%;
    position:absolute;
    color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#modal:target {
        opacity: 1;
        top:50%;
        visibility: visible;

    }


#modal .overlay {
    background-color: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}



.btn {
    padding:0 3em;
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:4;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:20px auto;
    display:block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 40px;


}
```

Here's my JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/agx4w5pm/1/

If you could edit my JSFIDDLE code that would be a great help.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The overlay div has no width...that could be it!

Comment: I Updated it myself here's what I got. http://jsfiddle.net/agx4w5pm/2/ technically its not correct. Instead of the background it turned out that the modal itself was included on the transparent area instead of just the background. Just wondering if you could offer help to me on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't understand your first point. But added rotation effect to your modal like you asked in second point. replace following classes

```
#modal {
    background:#97d2f1;
    left:50%;
    top:-50%;
    width:80%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin:-250px 0 0 -40%;
    position:absolute;
    color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    transition: all 1s ;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-perspective: 1500px; 
}

#modal:target {
        opacity: 1;
        top:50%;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
```

Notice  `-webkit-transform: rotateX(270deg);` property which is giving rotation effect.